# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string using drop down selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have three drop downs which retrieve the info from sql database(one column). When a user select WorkShopName from the first drop down, the second drop down shows available dates for it, and when the date is selected the user can choose the location from the third drop down. I am trying to insert the selected info from drop downs to another column in sql database. When i click button Register i have "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string". I tried to insert DateTime.Now Instead of Selected Value for Date Drop Down but the error is the same. Could any one help?
Thanx

Here are drop downs:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" 
            Text="Please select work shop you would like to register for:"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWorkShopName"  AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="workshopName" DataTextField="WorkshopName" 
            DataValueField="WorkshopName">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="workshopName" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WildLife_EducationConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [WorkshopName] FROM [tblWorkshop]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID = "lblChoseWDate" runat="server" Text="Please chose workshop date:"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChoseWDate" DataTextFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" 
            AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" DataSourceID="WorkshopDate2" 
            DataTextField="WorkshopBeginingDate" DataValueField="WorkshopBeginingDate">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="WorkshopDate2" runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WildLife_EducationConnectionString %>" 

            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT ([WorkshopBeginingDate]) FROM [tblWorkshop] WHERE ([WorkshopName] = @WorkshopName)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlWorkShopName" Name="WorkshopName" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblChoseWLoc" runat="server" Text="Please chose workshop location:"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChoseWorkShopLoc" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="WorkshopLocation2" DataTextField="WorkshopLocation" 
            DataValueField="WorkshopLocation">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="WorkshopLocation2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WildLife_EducationConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [WorkshopLocation] FROM [tblWorkshop] WHERE (([WorkshopBeginingDate] = @WorkshopBeginingDate) AND ([WorkshopName] = @WorkshopName))">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlChoseWDate" Type="String" 
                    Name="WorkshopBeginingDate" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlWorkShopName" Name="WorkshopName" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </td>
</tr>

<td>
    <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" onclick="btnRegister_Click" 
        Text="Register" />
</td>
```

And Code Behind for the button register:

```
SqlParameter workshopDate = new SqlParameter("@WorkshopDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    workshopDate.Value = ddlChoseWDate.SelectedValue;

using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CIS489_3\WILDLIFE;Initial Catalog=WildLife_Education;Integrated Security=True;"))
{
    SqlCommand CmdSql2 = new SqlCommand
    ("INSERT INTO [tblUserWorkshop] ([UserID],[WorkshopName],[WorkshopDate],[WorkshopLocation]) VALUES (@WorkshopName, @WorkshopDate, @WorkshopLocation, @UserID)", conn2);
    conn2.Open();

    CmdSql2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userId.ToString());
    CmdSql2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkshopName", ddlWorkShopName.SelectedValue);
    CmdSql2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkshopDate",workshopDate.Value);
    CmdSql2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkshopLocation", ddlChoseWorkShopLoc.SelectedValue);
CmdSql2.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn2.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure this has to be in the exact order given.

WRONG:

```
("INSERT INTO [tblUserWorkshop] ([UserID],[WorkshopName],[WorkshopDate],[WorkshopLocation]) VALUES (@WorkshopName, @WorkshopDate, @WorkshopLocation, @UserID)", conn2);
```

CORRECT:

```
("INSERT INTO [tblUserWorkshop] ([UserID],[WorkshopName],[WorkshopDate],[WorkshopLocation]) VALUES (@UserID, @WorkshopName, @WorkshopDate, @WorkshopLocation )", conn2);
```

You have the UserID at the end but should be in the front.

Pretty much you should specify your Inserts and Values into the same order. You are currently trying to covert the WorkShopLocation into a DateTime.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I totally forgot to check the sequence of values.

Comment: Yeah it's one of those 'face palm' moments. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CmdSql2.Parameters.Add("@WorkshopDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = workshopDate.Text;
```